# javascript 1.6 in 2005 async function

Tags: javascript, rhino

Company where i'm working are using rhino javascript engine. I have to make some async functions for optimization. Anyone can help me? There was any async this time (2005)?
How can i do that ?
unfortunately

```
let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var i = 0;

        setTimeout(function () {

            resolve("Success!");
            while (i <= 55) {
                i++
                console.log('h32123123mmm')

            }// Yay! Everything went well!
        }, 2500);

});

myFirstPromise.then((successMessage) => {
    console.log("Yay! " + successMessage);
});

myFirstPromise.then((successMessage) => {

    console.log("Yay! " + successMessage);
});
```

that won't work ...

i have to run some func async like:

```
function doSthAsync() { 
//do sth async
 } 
//rest of code not connected to doSthAsync()
```

Comment: Async did exist in 2005. That's what the A in AJAX meant. I think you meant  that promises didn't exist in 2005.

Comment: What's the actual question though? All you've shown us is some code that doesn't work in Rhino JS Engine.

Comment: how could i use AJAX on rhino javascript engine
i'm asking if in Rhino JS Engine was any form of async

Comment: Depends what you want to do. What is the question? "How to AJAX" is too open.

Comment: i have to run some func async|
like: " 

function doneAsync() {
    //do sth async 
}

//rest of code not connected to doneAsync()"

Comment: May you edit the question?

Comment: ye done i have hope thats enough